# visual studio code running executables on current code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code and have a few extensions installed, but what I want is to do what I do in notepad++ and set up a command so I can execute the open file (e.g. vbscript). I can do this easily in notepad++ but I've no idea how to do it in VS Code and the internet seems to not have much help either.

If it is possible, can it be done like the Python vs code extension and have the output window in a pane below the code?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an Extension that will run a number of different languages for you.

1. Install the [Code Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
2. Open the code file in Text Editor, then use shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+N`, or press `F1` and then select/type `Run Code`, the code will run and the output will be shown in the Output Window.